# Error while executing sql statement

Tags: db2

I am using IBM RAD.
I am executing following query.

```
Conn.prepareStatement("update UPLOAD set STATUS='Decrypted' WHERE PATH ='"+path+"'");
```

the datatype of `PATH` in DB2 is `VARCHAR`.

i am getting following error

`SQLCODE=-401,SQLSTATE=42818,SQLERRMC==,`

Comment: someone has edited your ques, I want to know if `WHERE PATH ='"+path+"'"` is what you entered, before edit it seemed something like : `WHERE PATH =""+path+""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means that you are comparing different data type.

**eg :**

`'12'=12`

Comment: i am comparing string with varchar in db2.

Comment: Are you sure its a VARCHAR or a "LONG VARCHAR",The error can occur due "LONG VARCHAR".